# Calculate hourly average of values in a time interval

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not really a sql guy, so maybe what I'm trying to do is simple, but I can't find an easy solution.

I have a series of hourly data, between two dates. Something like this:

```
DATETIME            VALUE
-------------------------
2014-01-01 01:00    104
2014-01-01 02:00    56
...
2014-01-04 23:00    65
2014-01-05 00:00    145
```

What I want is, for each hour, getting the average of the values of each day at that hour, so I end the query with something like this:

```
01:00    67.65
02:00    43.00
....
00:00    89.45
```

The "01:00" value will be the average of all the "01:00" values of each day, and so on.

The algorithm is easy, but my SQL skills are quite weak :-)

**BONUS**

It would be awesome if the answer would include a variation of the same problem: calculating the averages by weekdays and hour, and not only by hour:

```
Monday  01:00    34.23
Monday  02:00    54.34
...
Monday  23:00    241.34
Tuesday 00:00    89.43
....
Sunday  23:00    49.33
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [`GROUP BY`](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-use-group-by-in-sql-server) clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `datename` , `datepart` and `group by`

```
select datename(weekday, [datetime]) as [Day], 
       datepart(hour, [datetime]) as [Hour], 
       avg(value) as AvgValue,
       datepart(weekday, [datetime]) as [DayNo]
from table1
group by datename(weekday, [datetime]), datepart(weekday, [datetime]), 
         datepart(hour, [datetime])
order by datepart(weekday, [datetime]), datepart(hour, [datetime])
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of a general aggregate query you can use to group by a time interval.

```
WITH intervals AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, '', DATETIME), '') AS TimeInterval
    ,VALUE
    FROM dbo.Foo
    )
SELECT
      TimeInterval
    , DATENAME(weekday, TimeInterval) AS Weekday
    , CAST(TimeInterval AS time)
    , AVG(VALUE) AS AvgValue
FROM intervals
GROUP BY TimeInterval
ORDER BY TimeInterval;
```